Directing Packets further in the Network Stack from UMEM
I've been following the xdp-tutorial on GitHub to learn about eBPF and AF_XDP. I've encountered an issue while following the tutorial: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/advanced03-AF_XDP, is that although data is being transferred to the UMEM in user space (af_xdp_user.c) and I am able to get the statistics, but many of the packets are getting dropped after that. I had changed the process_packet function from the tutorial for a simple task, i.e, to count the number of TCP packets received.
The following is the code for the changed process_packet function:
static bool process_packet(struct xsk_socket_info *xsk,
                           uint64_t addr, uint32_t len)
{
    uint8_t *pkt = xsk_umem__get_data(xsk->umem->buffer, addr);

    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) pkt;
    struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (eth + 1);
    struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (ip + 1);

    if (ntohs(eth->h_proto) != ETH_P_IP ||
        len < (sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip) + sizeof(*tcp)) ||
        ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

In addition, I modified the provided BPF program from the tutorial to redirect all packets to the AF_XDP socket instead of every alternate packet.
However, when connecting to interfaces like lo and enp0s3, I observe that only a few packets are displayed, and websites do not load during this time. It seems like only initial packets are being processed, with subsequent packets likely being dropped. Hence I am not able to develop a connection to websites while that process runs.
How do I ensure all packets are properly processed and not dropped after transferring to UMEM?
